# Get unhealthy response during Blue/Green deployment on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Based on AWS document, `blue/green` deployment should offer zero down time during application deployment. I have a few services running on ECS Fargate. And `load balancer` checks the healthy of these containers. Sometimes I see this error message on ECS service events during deployment:

```
service my-api deregistered 1 targets in target-group my-api
f8c332f7-ac61-4791-9b08-6fe2ee4de792
2019-10-31 17:05:00 +1100
service my-api (port 443) is unhealthy in target-group my-api due to (reason Request timed out).
a306dabc-3961-42ba-8a08-814934409c9d
2019-10-31 17:03:32 +1100
service my-api registered 1 targets in target-group my-api
4333368f-682b-461f-9a3b-f38609b32589
```

It says `service my-api (port 443) is unhealthy`. And it recovers after a few seconds. I wonder why it reports `unhealthy`. What I understand is the deployment shouldn't happen until it is healthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/bluegreen-deployments-with-amazon-ecs/) by AWS, you can update and roll back features with near zero downtime, so to say that in some cases a minimal downtime could be anticipated.

But more specifically to answer your question, if I understand your log correctly, it seems your targets are deregistering from your target group, which corresponds to the target group not passing the health check until the next target is being registered. (Is your target group configuration currently consists of 1 target?)

What I would suggest is to configure your blue-green deployment as follows.
Using your ALB/NLB have two separate target groups, each serving either the blue or the green environment.

Once you would like to update your service, make sure the your ALB/NLB routes the appropriate "Production" traffic to both the blue and green target groups.

Finally, adjust your ALB/NLB to route traffic exclusively to the green target group, and have the blue target group as backup in case a roll-back is in order.

I would suggest consulting this [sample guidance blog](https://github.com/aws-samples/ecs-blue-green-deployment) from AWS, that leverages Amazon Code* services and AWS Lambda to automate much of the process.

Or Alternatively, [look into this blog](https://spotinst.com/blog/implementing-bluegreen-deployments-spotinst/) on how to deploy a blue-green deployment using Spotinst Ocean.